# UIWebView rendering web pages in a low-quality zoomed in state

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

Using UIWebView to render Third party websites. I cant use WKWebView for various reasons.

There is no Xib/View in storyboard associated with my ViewController. All the UI is loaded in the viewDidLoad() method

```
    let navigationBar = UINavigationBar()
    navigationBar.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
    //added navigation items
    self.view.addSubview(navigationBar)

    UXHelper.createHorizontalConstraints(navigationBar, outerView: self.view, margin: 0)
    UXHelper.createConstraint(navigationBar, parent: self.view, to: self.view, constraint: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, margin: 0)
    UXHelper.createConstraint(navigationBar, parent: self.view, to: nil, constraint: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, margin: AlgoLinkWebViewController.navBarHeight)

    self.webView = UIWebView()
    self.webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.webView.opaque = false
    self.webView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    self.webView.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(self.webView)

    UXHelper.createHorizontalConstraints(self.webView, outerView: self.view, margin: 0)
    UXHelper.createConstraint(self.webView, parent: self.view, to: self.view, constraint: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, margin: 0)
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.webView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: navigationBar, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
```

With the above code below is the screenshot of the webView rendered

[image: UI WebView with bigger font for Web Content]

The expected WebView rendering I am looking for is . This is from a different app that I know uses UIWebView but don't have access to code

[image: UI WebView with the expected Font size]

NOTE: PLEASE ignore the navigation bar differences

The options I tried are

1. remove Autoresizing = false

   - Removing this did not remove the zoomed in state
2. webView.scalesWebPagesToFit = true

   - setting this did not make a difference
3. Initializing UIWebView with the parent view frame size

   - self.webView = UIWebView(frame: self.view.bounds) - no difference
4. Set the scroll view scale value to 0.5

   - did not make a difference

Comment: What are the differences? Looks like just the font size and the status bar is it right?

Comment: Yes it is indeed the font size that is important here. Both of them are rendering the exact same Wikipedia web page and as you can see in my code, I am not injecting any javascript to make the web view look like having bigger font size. I am also taking screenshots of the web view for my app purposes and due to the bigger font size the screenshot looks pixelated and crappy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you use zoom mode at your iPhone6/6plus.

Comment: You are partially right in that it is a zoom mode issue. What happened was the app I was adding features to ( not my app) had a launch screen resolution set to be in Zoom mode. I did not realize that "Zoom" mode is a app-level setting that can be set at launch.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement changes in the font size you can use Java Script to do so by adding the fallowing in your viewDidLoad method

```
var fontSize = 104 //Your preferred font size go here
var jsString = "document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.fontSize='\(fontSize)px'"
    webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(jsString)
webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(jsString)
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I don't want to force the font size. My UIWebView should be generic to be able to open any website ( almost any third party website can be opened) .. I want to set the initial state of my webView to be able to render like the second screenshot I have . I am a newbie to Swift and Apple app coding in general. I feel like I am missing some small  gotcha that will make my UIWebView rendering go from the first image to the second